# Bootstrap 4: Buttongroup - change active color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a buttongroup with bootstrap 4 and everything is fine

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Right</button>
</div>
```

How can I highlight the selected state more? E.g. I want a red background color of the active button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply `data-toggle="button"` to the wrapper element the child buttons will automatically have `.active` applied to whichever button is clicked.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group" role="group" data-toggle="button" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Right</button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Note: This `.active` class can be applied to any number of `<button>` elements within the group; if your intention is to make `.active` unique you may need to extend this a bit with some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
.btn:active {background : red}
```