# Change Bootstrap button group properties

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button group from Bootstrap :

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
            </label>
      </div>
```

Maybe its basic but, I am trying to change :

1. background color of selected/unselected
2. text - font/color

and nothing works. Like this one :
[Bootstrap 4: Buttongroup - change active color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110674/bootstrap-4-buttongroup-change-active-color)

Answer (score 6):

you need

```
/* selected btn css */
.btn-group-toggle .btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .btn-group-toggle .btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .show>.btn.dropdown-toggle {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      border-color: #2196F3;
}

/* non selected btn css */
.btn-group-toggle .btn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b7b7b7;
  border-color: #6c757d;
}
```

so it will look like this

[image]

see demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgLGXP

Comment: This will not work for me, the buttons stay the same, given the exact html I typed here.

Answer (score 2):

Just put following property to `.active` class.

```
.active{
   background-color: #8064A2 !important;
}
```

and you are done.

```css
.active{
   background-color: #8064A2 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
            </label>
      </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question you want the same effect as the other SO post you linked.

Try adding this css:

```css
.btn .btn-secondary, .active {
  background-color: #e21833 !important;
  border-color: #e21833 !important;
  color: yellow !important;
}

.btn .btn-secondary, .active:hover {
  background-color: #900900 !important;
  border-color: #900900 !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br><br><br>
  
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
            </label>
      </div>
  
  

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `!Important` property for your CSS.

```css
.btn.active {
    background-color: lime !important;
    border-color: lime !important;
    color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but how do you set the background color of unselected button? and text color also ?

Comment: It's best to give the `btn-group` a unique ID and use CSS selectors.
`UniqueID.btn` for all inactive buttons, 
`UniqueID.btn.active` fo the active button